# Redirecting Wordpress permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

How can I redirect a Wordpress permalink from

```
example.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html
```

to

```
example.com/%postname%
```

I have tried doing it through a plugin and also by adding the following code to `.htaccess` file but it's returning 404 not found error.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure it is above the default WordPress rewrite rules.

E.g.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Glad it worked.  If it is the correct answer, please click the checkmark icon to the left of my answer to accept it.